# when to use 〜の中で、中には

Tags: particle-は, に-and-で

I think I answered this question for myself while writing it, but maybe someone can confirm: When to use 「の中で」 versus 「の中には」or something similar to mean "among X"?

For example, I pulled this sentence off the internet:
田中さんは兄弟の中で上から２番目です。

But:
ここの蔵書の中には、お金で買えない貴重な本もあるんだって。

Is it that you use で when the subject of the sentence comes before the 中, and には when the main phrase of the sentence (subject and verb) come after the 中? Would you ever say just 「中に」, or 「中では」?

Answer (score 7):

You use locative に ("[to be/exist / there's ~~] in [place]") with verbs ある, いる, 住む, 泊まる, etc., eg:

> お金は銀行**にあり**ます。
>   山田さんは東京**にいる**。

Hence your second example:

> ここの蔵書の中**に**は、お金で買えない貴重な本も**ある**んだって。

に is used because of the verb ある. ～～の中に here means "[to be/exist / there's~~] among [group of people/things]" and can be used with いる, ある, etc. A few examples:

> 「弟子**の中に**裏切り者が**いる**。」
>   「果物**の中に**は、アレルギーを起こすものも**あります**。」

As for the は in your example, it's a topical or contrastive particle. You can also use 「中に」, as in:

> 「ここの蔵書の中**に**(は)、夏目漱石の本がある。」
>   「夏目漱石の本は、ここの蔵書の中**に**ある。」

---

You use locative で ("[to do/be~~] in/at [place]") with other verbs, adjectives or copulas, eg:

> 「コンビニ**で**弁当を**買っ**た。」
>   「図書館(の中)**で**は、**飲食でき**ません。」
>   「その歌手は日本**で**も**有名です**。」

Hence your first example:

> 田中さんは兄弟**の中で**上から２番目**です**。

～～の中で here means "[to do/be~~] among [group of people/things]". A few examples:

> 「果物**の中で**リンゴが一番**好きです**。」
>   「佐藤さんは、弟子**の中で**一番**優秀だ**。」

You could also use 「中では」, like this:

> 「山田君は兄弟**の中では**一番背が**高い**ですが、クラス**では**３番目**です**。」
>   　<sup>(The は in では is contrastive, and the は in 山田君は is topical.)</sup>
>   「クラス**の中では**、鈴木さんが一番よく**勉強します**。」